# Can't access the option variable while looping on array of strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to access options on `select` based on value. I have the array from backend then I converted it to JavaScript array, but I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #workShop option[value=parentClosedWS[i]]

When I print the `ParentCloseWS`, it has values like this `["str1", "str2"]`
Here is the code:

```
var parentClosedWS = <?php echo json_encode($parentClosedWS);?>;
var closedWS = <?php echo json_encode($closedWS );?>;
console.log(closedWS);
console.log(parentClosedWS);
for (i = 0; i < parentClosedWS.length; i++) {
  console.log(typeof(parentClosedWS[i]));
  var parent = String(parentClosedWS[i]);
  console.log(parent);
  $("#workShop option[value=" + 'parentClosedWS[i]' + "]").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<select id="workShop" class="floatLabel" name="workshopsel">
  <option value="" class="empty"></option>
  <option value="Marketing">Marketing </option>
  <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
  <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
  <option value="HR">HR</option>
  <option value="Supply chain">Supply chain</option>
  <option value="Media production">Media production</option>
  <option value="Development">Development</option>
  <option value="TOT">TOT</option>
  <option value="Project management">Project management</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Provide the HTML as well.

Comment: Please provide **explicit** sample data - (What is `$parentClosedWS`, what is `$closedWS`?), same with yor **console output**. Another problem of you: You want to access `parentClosedWS[i]` but you had created here a **STRING** and don't call the object correctly!

Comment: `$(\`#workShop option[value=${parentClosedWS[i]}]\`).prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quotes around `parentClosedWS[i];`. Those single quotes are converting it to that specific string, rather than giving you the value.

The line should read:

```
$("#workShop option[value=" + parentClosedWS[i] + "]").prop('disabled', true);
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var parentClosedWS = ["HR", "IT"];
for (i = 0; i < parentClosedWS.length; i++) {
  $("#workShop option[value=" + parentClosedWS[i] + "]").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="workShop" class="floatLabel" name="workshopsel">
  <option value="" class="empty"></option>
  <option value="Marketing">Marketing </option>
  <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
  <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
  <option value="HR">HR</option>
  <option value="Supply chain">Supply chain</option>
  <option value="Media production">Media production</option>
  <option value="Development">Development</option>
  <option value="TOT">TOT</option>
  <option value="Project management">Project management</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's exactly what ES6 template literals simplify alot: `$(\`#workShop option[value=${parentClosedWS[i]}]\`).prop('disabled', true);`